# How to make Windows 11 forget USB-C hub (monitor)

Tags: windows-11, external-display, usb-c

I have a Dell Windows 11 laptop attached to a USB-C hub to which I attach my monitor with HDMI. This setup was working well, until I run Dell firmware updater and a hit a bluescreen during the update. Upon retry the update finished, but the monitor is no longer working with this USB hub. I suppose I somehow need to "reset" this monitor in Windows, but I don't know how.

Other devices work fine with the hub. The monitor works if I use a different hub / adapter. I dual boot Linux in this machine, and the monitor works with my usual hub normally in Linux. So just the combination of this hub and monitor is troublesome, for Windows.

The laptop also has a discrete NVIDIA GPU built in.

If the hub is plugged in without the monitor attached to the hub, Windows
display manager shows it as a display that is disconnected. I cannot make Windows
forget this display ever existed.

What I tried:

- reinstalled intel integrated graphics drivers (downloaded from Dell)
- reinstalling Nvidia drivers (uninstalled from device manager)
- uninstalling all monitors from device manager
- uninstall all usb devices from device manager
- removed from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\` registry the folders Configuration, Connectivity, ScaleManager
- all kinds of restarts, with the monitor plugged in and out

What's the proper way to make windows forget this display and make it work again?

Comment: What devices did the Dell firmware updater update? Have you tried to delete the hub in Device Manager and reboot?

Comment: I don't know how to get this information from the Dell updater.. Yes, I did uninstall USB hubs from the device manager.

Comment: Since Linux works correctly in exactly the same hardware configuration, but Windows doesn't, it looks to me after all like a Windows driver problem. Have you installed a driver for the monitor (if one exists)? What is this monitor?

Comment: Good call, unfortunaly there seems to be no dedicated driver available for this monitor: https://www.asus.com/us/Displays-Desktops/Monitors/Gaming/VG245H/HelpDesk_Download/

Comment: If you have System Restore enabled, then try to roll Windows back to a time before you ran the Dell firmware updater.